# textview becomeFirstResponder in UICollectionView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

i've problem which is in UICollection i've 4 indexPath (0 to 3). when from indexPath 2 to 3 my textView still won't focus, i've tried all article but still stuck,in otherwise some of my friends said because the cell was nil ?

here's my code : http://pasted.co/90c7f3d9

sorry someone delete my code.

Comment: You should always try and add the code with the question in case the url goes stale and users will be more inclined to help.

Comment: someone delete my code sir, here's the new link : http://pasted.co/90c7f3d9

Comment: Ok, point still stands - that site bombed slightly on chrome and pops up some slightly NSFW advertising.  Not to mention there's so much code in there, which is going to be off-putting to most users.  If you want some traction on this question, I would suggest pulling the code out of the link and on here creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PhilCooper done, i ask my Senior for the solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

my senior found the solution, while u're using animateWithDuration and want show the keyboard, should input becomeFirstResponder in "animateWithDuration" with "Completion", here's the solution :

```
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
            [self.rateReviewExpertView.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(3.0f*(CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds)), 0.0f)];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            RateReviewExpertCollectionViewCell *cell = (RateReviewExpertCollectionViewCell *)[self.rateReviewExpertView.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:3 inSection:0]];

            [cell.textView becomeFirstResponder];
        }];
```